# Making request to Google Cloud Video API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Video API to analyse some videos.
I am trying to make the annotation request and it should be like this

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data '{"inputUri":"gs://YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_OBJECT","features":["LABEL_DETECTION"]}'\
  "https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1/videos:annotate"
```

My question is I have no idea what YOUR_BUCKET and YOUR_OBJECT represent? and there is no where on the documentation that specifies what this parameters are. Can someone help tell me what they are?

Answer (score 1):

That url (`gs://.....`) indicates a google cloud storage location (url).

If you look at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/label-tutorial), it says

> To run your application, simply pass it the Cloud Storage URI of a video:
> gs://YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_OBJECT

`YOUR_BUCKET` is referring to the name of your cloud storage bucket while `YOUR_OBJECT` is the name of the video file

Comment: In Cloud Storage, the object name is the full path (path/to/object.file).